# Is it possible to refer to entity itself in subquery filter?

Tags: hibernate, orm, subquery

I have to make Criteria for entity A, using subquery for entity B(having entity A as field). To avoid cache miss I have to reject id based queries.

Thats pseudo code example

```
DetachedCriteria criteriaA = (criteria for A)....


DetachedCriteria bCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class);
                bCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq(".....));
                bCriteria.add(Restrictions.ge(....));
                bCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("A"));

Criterion  criterion = Subqueries.in("A entity", bCriteria);//here i want to refer to entity A

criteriaA.add(criterion);
```

Comment: What happens when you test it? And what do you mean with "To avoid cache miss I have to reject id based queries"?

Comment: When I add/remove entities to table B and then select entity A via query where entities id is used - the output does not change

Comment: So in fact, the problem is not how to create the criteria query, which works fine, but returns results from the query cache even when these results are obsolete due to the creation of new B instances. Is that right?

Comment: Short answer:Yes Long answer: the problem is in cache, it's true. I found it and optimized most of queries to suit cache limitations. I can not change cache cause there is to much things depends on it.

Comment: cache: I use EHCache. Also IO made experiment with SimpleCache -same result

Comment: I think you're just hitting a Hibernate bug which doesn't consider entities referenced in subqueries to know if a query "depends" on an entity. This implies that Hibernate thinks the cache results are still valid, although they're not anymore. Try invalidating the cache before executing the query, or making this query not cacheable.

Comment: Yes. I tried. It works but does not suits.